# In PyQt5, How to add a QSpinBox inside a QTreeWidget cell?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidget

I'm trying to add a QSpinBox inside some cells of the QTreeWidget tree_parameters.

```
l1 = QTreeWidgetItem(["String A", "", ""])
l2 = QTreeWidgetItem(["String AA", "", ""])
for i in range(3):
    l1_child = QTreeWidgetItem(["Child A" + str(i), "Child B" + str(i), "Child C" + str(i)])
    l1.addChild(l1_child)

for j in range(2):
    l2_child = QTreeWidgetItem(["Child AA" + str(j), "Child BB" + str(j), "Child CC" + str(j)])
    l2.addChild(l2_child)

self.tree_parameters.resize(500, 200)
self.tree_parameters.setColumnCount(3)
self.tree_parameters.setHeaderLabels(["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"])
self.tree_parameters.addTopLevelItem(l1)
self.tree_parameters.addTopLevelItem(l2)


item = QTreeWidgetItem()
widget = QSpinBox()
widget.setValue(5)
self.tree_parameters.setItemWidget(item, 1, widget)
```

With this code it appears the tree, but not the QSpinBox widget added using setItemWidget function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#setItemWidget):

> **void QTreeWidget::setItemWidget(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int column,
>   QWidget *widget)**
>
> Sets the given widget to be displayed in the cell specified by the
>   given item and column.
>
> [...]

What you should do first is to add the item, and then just add the widget in a specific column, in your case for example we add the item to the top and then place it in the second column:

```
item = QTreeWidgetItem()
self.tree_parameters.addTopLevelItem(item)
widget = QSpinBox()
widget.setValue(5)
self.tree_parameters.setItemWidget(item, 1, widget)
```

[image]